# How to add Application Insights to Azure Timer function in .Net 5

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5

I'm looking for an equivalent of `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();` used in Asp.Net Core to the configure service in Azure Timer function .Net5 isolated process.

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, s) =>
    { 
        // Get IConfiguration
        var configuration = hostBuilderContext.Configuration;

        // Configure Application Insights. How?

        // Configure services based on config settings
           
    })
    .Build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your function code use `ILogger` log methods, logging to application insights is already hooked up in the functions runtime. All you need to tell the runtime is the way to connect to the application insights instance. You will do this by providing an instrumentation key or a connection string(recommended).

If you already have an application insights resource created in azure, go to **Configure -> Properties** and copy the value of a setting called `CONNECTION STRING`

[image]

The functions runtime code looks for a configuration entry with key `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING`and use it's value when hooking up the logger to application insights instance. Environment variables are a valid source when building the configuration. That means you can create an environment variable for this and that will be read.

In azure portal, go to your functions resource page. Go to **Setting -> Configuration** and add a new application setting entry. The application settings you add here will be exposed as environment variables at runtime.

The name of the settings should be `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` and value should be the connection string value you copied in previous step. After saving the entry, you should see something like this
[image]

Once you add a new entry, azure portal will ask you to restart the app (so that it can pick up the new setting entry, rebuild the configuration used for logging). After the app is restarted, you should be able to see the entries in your application insight logs-> traces table.

[image]

Comment: How do you specify the application insights key or connection string in host.json file?

Comment: Ideally, you should not consider storing that in a file within your source code. It is not secure. If you absolutely need to it to read it from a  local config, you can do that by adding another local json file as the IConfiguration source inside your Program.cs code.